# How to use variable from one file in another file, who imports the first file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to start making games in python with pygame. I made a couple of games on js. I like to make my games oop. When I use classes in js I split them in files. Now I am creating simple game with python(it's was my first js game). Like in js I split my objects into separate files. Now I am creating my draw method  in the player class. I don't know how to draw the rectangle, who is my player to the window(the window is created in a file called main.py, but the draw method is in file called Player.py)
The problem is that when I start the game it just shows me white window.

Here are my codes:
main.py:

```
import pygame

from Player import Player

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Guitar Hero");
done = False
WW, WH = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()

player = Player(0, 0, 0, WW, WH)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        done = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        player.move(1)
                        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        player.move(2)
                        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

        player.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

and my Player.py:

```
import pygame

WW, WH = 0, 0

class Player:
    """Player for Guitar Hero
        content:
            draw function,
            move function
    """
    def __init__(self, x, y, state, windowWidth, windowHeght):
        WW = windowWidth
        WH = windowHeght
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.state = state
    def draw(self, surface):
        self.y = self.state * WH / 4
        #help me with this line
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, WW / 50, WH / 4))
    def move(self, direction):
        if direction == 1 and self.state > 0:
            self.state -= 1
        else:
            self.state += 1
```

P.S.: If the Player class is in the main.py file everything works fine!

Comment: That does not look like an import problem. `player.draw()` is most likely throwing an exception. There should be an error message appearing on the Python console.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK No, there isn't any errors in the console. Just the screen is white.

Comment: The graphical screen is separate from the console; if you run your program from the console instead of double-clicking the `.py` file, you should see the game opening in a separate window, and something should appear on the console.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK I am on ubuntu and I am running the game with the terminal.

Comment: OK, from that information, all I can conclude so far is that the error has no relation with the fact that the variable comes from another file.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK If I just use screen in the player.py file, it gives error. If I put the surface like argument of the function draw, there is no error, but nothing draws on the screen.